# sql get zero as value if no records been found

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a simple question i'm looking around but cant have it work for me. I have made an query with current date and lets say tomorow is tuesday but there is no data in it yet because it is the future. And there can't be a record in it yet.

When i run the query it simply shows nothing only 2 colums called `total | Date`
It does what I say. But now I want it to show me `0` instead of noting but only 2 colums.

I did search for COALESCE but for some reason it did not work it also give me no errors.

```
SELECT
    SUM(totalExcl) AS total, 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_add, '%W') AS 'Date'  
FROM
    ex.ps_ox_quotation 
WHERE 
    WEEK(date_add) = WEEK (UTC_TIMESTAMP()) 
        AND saleType IN ('IEW' , 'A', 'Project')
        AND DAYOFWEEK(date_add) % 6 > 4 
GROUP BY Date 
ORDER BY 'Date' DESC
```

What I have(table) =

```
| |total | Date
```

What I want(table) =

```
| |total | Date
     0     Tuesday
```

Today is Wednesday so it is current date and this is what it shows (btw this is current) i'm just showing it:

```
| |total | Date
    500    Wednesday
```

Comment: I think you need `` @@ROWCOUNT`` for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
IF(SUM(totalExcl) is NULL,0,SUM(totalExcl)) AS total, 
DAYNAME(date_add) AS 'Date'  
FROM
ex.ps_ox_quotation 
WHERE 
WEEK(date_add) = WEEK (UTC_TIMESTAMP()) 
    AND saleType IN ('IEW' , 'A', 'Project')
    AND DAYOFWEEK(date_add) % 6 > 4 
GROUP BY Date 
ORDER BY 'Date' DESC
```

or you can do this way

```
SELECT
IF(SUM(totalExcl) is NULL,0,SUM(totalExcl)) AS total, 
IF(DATE_FORMAT(date_add, '%W') is null,DAYNAME(now()),DATE_FORMAT(date_add, '%W')) AS 'Date'  
FROM
ex.ps_ox_quotation 
WHERE 
WEEK(date_add) = WEEK (UTC_TIMESTAMP()) 
    AND saleType IN ('IEW' , 'A', 'Project')
    AND DAYOFWEEK(date_add) % 6 > 4 
GROUP BY Date 
ORDER BY 'Date' DESC
```

Comment: Thanks I will try asap.

Comment: Ok after try tell me.

Comment: The 1st one did work but gives me a NULL at column Date. The 2nd one did also the job and gave me no null but the actual day name at column Date. And for both it gave me a zero (o) at column total if there was no record in it yet, so it did the job. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with **IFNULL**...

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(SUM(totalExcl),0) AS total, 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_add, '%W') AS 'Date'  
FROM
    ex.ps_ox_quotation 
WHERE 
    WEEK(date_add) = WEEK (UTC_TIMESTAMP()) 
        AND saleType IN ('IEW' , 'A', 'Project')
        AND DAYOFWEEK(date_add) % 6 > 4 
GROUP BY Date 
ORDER BY 'Date' DESC
```